# laravel automatically make requests to /api/... XMLHttpRequest

Tags: laravel, xmlhttprequest

I need to send an `XMLHttpRequest` header with all my requests in order to get a JSON response

Is it possible to have this as the default behavior for all API routes?

EDIT:

laravel automatically redirects to the home route when a request fails (e.g. request validation error).

However, when I define the `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` header I receive a json response telling me what went wrong.

Since all my endpoints under `/api` are json specific I would like to default to this behavior without having to define the header.

Comment: Hey Chris, it's not quite clear what you're trying to achieve. Maybe you could try including some code and add a bit more to the question so that more people can help you?

Comment: Generally you approach this from the other side and set default header on your frontend ajax requests. Laravel by default already does this for axios. https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js#L24

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this with a "before" middleware, using the middleware to inject the `X-Requested-With` header into the request.

Create `app/Http/Middleware/ForceXmlHttpRequest.php`:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class ForceXmlHttpRequest
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $request->headers->set('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Apply the middleware to your `api` middleware group. Edit `app/Http/Kernel.php`:

```
'api' => [
    'throttle:60,1',
    'bindings',
    \App\Http\Middleware\ForceXmlHttpRequest::class,
],
```

This does, of course, take control away from the requester. As far as the framework is concerned, every request made to the `api` middleware group will be treated as an ajax request, and there will be no way for the requester to say otherwise. Just something to keep in mind.

NB: untested.